# Alternating p series. given that summation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Given that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{k^2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\ $$

Show that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{12}\ $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1^2} - \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} - \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} - \frac{1}{6^2} + \dots\\
=\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dots\right) - 2\left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{4^2} + \frac{1}{6^2} + \dots\right)\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{2}{2^2}\left(\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} + \dots\right)\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
= \frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}-2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Short and sweet; your style!

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$A=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(2k-1)^2}}$$

$$B=\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(2k)^2}}$$

then $A+B=\frac\pi6$, $B=\frac14\cdot\frac\pi6=\frac\pi{24}$, so

$$A-B=(A+B)-2B=\dotsb$$